# Value cannot be null when launch Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

My current project was a blank project in which I copied the page and classes of Visual Studio's example, as I'm trying to understand how everything works in there.

Now, my project gets compiled, but when I run it I get

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   newRoot    at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.SetPage(Page
>   newRoot)    at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsBasePage.LoadApplication(Application
>   application)    at MyApp.UWP.MainPage..ctor()    at
>   MyApp.UWP.MyApp_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_4_MainPage()
>   at MyApp.UWP.MyApp_UWP_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
>   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object
>   parameter)    at MyApp.UWP.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)

I would like to understand where this comes from and correct it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer:
This happened because I removed

```
MainPage = new MyApp.MainPage();
```

from MyApp\App.xaml.cs

Actually I had removed it and put it back, but for some reason, it appears that this type of project isn't really update until I did a new "Build" + "Deploy". I'm used to have to just re-build and had not re-deployed so my changes were not taken into account yet.